# object passing as paramter in update method can be in either in persistent state or detached state?

Tags: hibernate

As per hibernate doc(at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object)) for update method 
void update(Object object) throws HibernateException here  object as parameter is said to be in detached state.But i tried some examples where 
this object passed can be a object in persistent state too.So what i did is

```
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);
person.setName("scott");
// At this point of time person is in persistent stage as it has adentifier attached to it and also attached to session.
session.update(person);
```

it updated succesfully. **So as per my understanding passed object as paramter in update method can be in either in persistent state or detached state right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So as per my understanding passed object as paramter in update method
>   can be in either in persistent state or detached state right?

Yes , you can pass the persistent object or detached object to the `update()` . But `update()`  only has effect on the detached object. Calling update() on the persistent object is **redundancy** and **does nothing** because the object is already persistent which its  state  will automatically synchronize to the DB during flushing . So ,from your code , person's name can be updated to  `scott` is due to flushing , but not due to update(). You can proof it  by removing `update()`  and the name can still be updated to the `scott`!

`update()` only has effect on the detached object  , which can make the detached instance persistent and managed by the hibernate session.

Answer (score -1):

That's odd. My documentation for update() is:

> Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given
>   detached instance. If there is a persistent instance with the same
>   identifier, an exception is thrown. This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   cascade="save-update".

So, I don't think it works for detached objects. I generally merge() them first or refresh() the object if it's detached.

Have you tried it by closing the session, opening a new one and then updating?

Comment: `update()` only has effect and it is supposed to work on the detached objects only.